# Matplotlib in Python is not plotting a waveform. It is displaying some random lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, waveform

I am trying a plot a signal. Instead of displaying a waveform, the matplotlib is plotting random lines. Require your inputs

Below is the code that I used for plotting a signal

```
file=pd.read_csv('/content/signals.csv',skiprows=1)
file=file.iloc[:,[0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=2)

fig.suptitle('Display Signals')
axs[0,0].plot(file.iloc[:, 0], file.iloc[:, 1])

axs[1,0].plot(file.iloc[:, 0], file.iloc[:, 14])
axs[0,1].plot(file.iloc[:, 0], file.iloc[:, 5])
axs[1,1].plot(file.iloc[:, 0], file.iloc[:, 10])
```

Below is the data used
[image: Data]

[image: Plots Displayed]

Comment: Your csv looks like maybe it needs more precision.  1.67e9 is repeated a bunch of times.

Comment: @ Jody Klymak
 Your suggestion solved my issue. Thanks!